# Errors during boot, computer will not finish booting

Tags: boot, bios, acpi

I recently got a new Windows 10 HP laptop which my colleague installed Ubuntu on.  It's been working fine for a few days, but it recently started getting stuck in the middle of booting and it freezes after showing these messages:

```
[0.935488] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 231587/13623296 files, 51804463/54492928 blocks
[3.745940] spi-nor spi0.0: BFPT parsing failed. Please consider using SPI_NO
[4.168849]
[5.073252] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[5.073285] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[5.331464] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
```

Besides that the screen is black and there is a blinking cursor line below the last error message.  I've tried looking up some of the errors but I can only find solutions that dont work for me, or people saying it's not a problem.  Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You've provided few specifics; what Ubuntu product (Server?, Desktop?, Core?), what release of that product, have you tried limiting the boot to runlevel 1 or recovery?